# Python/JSON KeyError

Tags: python, json

Please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887426/cant-remember-how-to-find-this-in-json-file) for more info I am trying to find something like this

```
screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']
```

but for a new JSON file but I keep getting

> KeyError: 'screenshots'

I tried a few things to fix it but nothing works so any help will be welcomed

**JSON**

```
    {
"minVersion":"0.1",
"class":"DepictionTabView",
"tintColor":"#2cb1be",
"headerImage":"",
"tabs":[ {
    "tabname":"Details",
    "class":"DepictionStackView",
    "tintColor":"#2cb1be",
    "views":[ {
        "class": "DepictionSubheaderView", "useBoldText": true, "useBottomMargin": false, "title": "Description"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionMarkdownView", "markdown": "<p>This is a description...<\/p>", "useRawFormat": true
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSubheaderView", "useBoldText": true, "useBottomMargin": false, "title": "Screenshots"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class":"DepictionScreenshotsView",
        "itemCornerRadius":6,
        "itemSize":"{160, 284.44444444444}",
        "screenshots":[ {
            "accessibilityText": "Screenshot", "url": "Screenshot URL 1"
        }
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSubheaderView", "useBoldText": true, "useBottomMargin": false, "title": "Information"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionTableTextView", "title": "Author", "text": "User"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionTableTextView", "title": "Version", "text": "1.0"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionTableTextView", "title": "Price", "text": "free"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSpacerView", "spacing": 16
    }
    ,
    {
        "class":"DepictionStackView",
        "views":[ 
        {
            "class": "DepictionTableButtonView", "title": "Support", "action": "", "openExternal": true
        }
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionSpacerView", "spacing": 16
    }
    ]
}
,
{
    "tabname":"Changelog",
    "class":"DepictionStackView",
    "tintColor":"#2cb1be",
    "views":[ 
    {
        "class": "DepictionSubheaderView", "useBoldText": true, "useBottomMargin": false, "title": "1.0"
    }
    ,
    {
        "class": "DepictionMarkdownView", "markdown": "<ul>\n<li>Initial release.<\/li>\n<\/ul>", "useRawFormat": true
    }
    ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: There is no screenshots in the second view object. `screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][4]['screenshots']` would potentially remove your error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you could update your question and explain why you're trying to look for the `screenshots` key on a view that does not have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, many of the views do not have a `screenshots` key. The 2nd view (`views[1]`) definitely does not while the 5th view (`views[4]`) does.

If you're trying to collect all the screenshots from the views you'll need to use a loop and some conditional logic to find them.

```
screenshots = [] # an accumulator to collect our screenshots
for view in full_data['tabs'][0]['views']: # loop over each view
    if 'screenshots' in view: # only process views with a screenshots key
        # there can be multiple screenshots per view, so concatenate them to our accumulator
        screenshots += view['screenshots']
```

You can further simplify this to a list comprehension

```
screenshots = [*screenshot for screenshot in full_data['tabs'][0]['views'] if 'screenshots' in view]
```

The `*screenshot` tells Python to "unroll" the list of screenshots. Adding each item to the list, rather then inserting a list *into* our list.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted:

```
screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']
```

Goes to:

```
{
        "class": "DepictionMarkdownView", "markdown": "<p>This is a description...<\/p>", "useRawFormat": true
}
```

Which doesn't have any key called `screenshots`. Your JSON keys at that level are not guaranteed to have that key. I'm guessing that `screenshots` will only be there if `class` is `DepictionScreenshotsView`. 
So you can try:

```
tab = full_data['tabs'][0]
screen_shots = [tab['views'][i]['screenshots'] for i in range(len(tab)) if tab['view'][i]['class'] == 'DepictionScreenshotsView')
```